# New Guid Id - 2 GUID

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

they asked me to write ids on the tables. They said it was too long to use Guid Id. How can I do a short guid. Or is there anything I can start from 1?

[image: result image]

Comment: just curious, who's `they`?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB accepts arbitrary values as IDs. If you do not provide IDs, MongoDB will generate them for you. If you wish to use short IDs, you can use integers starting with 1.

Comment: but how ?  can use integers starting with 1.

Comment: The same way you are providing other attributes, you could say:

{foo: 'bar', id: 1}